# Only services as an android app

Tags: android, service, background-process

I want to make an android app that is going act as a middle ware system rather than an actual application. I want it to be comprised of bunch of services that communicates to various servers and to each other. There is no need of UI or Activity. Is this possible or will I have to make a dummy Activity? How do I achieve this ? and how do I start all the services and make communication between them?

Comment: it is possible but there is no guarantee that your service/s stay running forever, the OS can kill a service when it needs to

Comment: So how do I ensure its execution? Make an activity and keep it as current running Activity?

Comment: there is no way to ensure execution uless you make your own from and make the app a system app. system apps like google play services do not have this limitation